# Not able to start Apache

Tags: apache, openssl

Not able to start apache. Giving the below error.
Could some one please help me on this?

Error message:

ip-10-128-9-27 httpd-scl-wrapper: httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-ssl.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /lib64/libcrypto.so.10: version `OPENSSL_1.0.2' not found (required by /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/modules/mod_ssl.so)

Comment: Open your configuration file "httpd.conf" and look at line 1, or add it to your post.

Comment: ]# cat /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
#
# This is the main Apache HTTP server configuration file.  It contains the
# configuration directives that give the server its instructions.
# See <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/> for detailed information.

Comment: I really wanted to see the actual config file as the second error message implies there is something wrong with the file.  Also the link you posted doesn't work.

Comment: # cat /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-ssl.conf
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

Comment: I think this is not related to any changes in config files, because it use to work properly with the same configuration. May be it is not able to load the modules?

Comment: If you post the file then we can check.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the detailed error message.

```
[root@ip-10-128-9-27 centos]# systemctl status httpd24-httpd.service
● httpd24-httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd24-httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2017-12-07 12:34:05 UTC; 12s ago
  Process: 29020 ExecStop=/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd-scl-wrapper $OPTIONS -k graceful-stop (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 29018 ExecStart=/opt/rh/httpd24/root/usr/sbin/httpd-scl-wrapper $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 29018 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 07 12:34:05 ip-10-128-9-27 systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Dec 07 12:34:05 ip-10-128-9-27 httpd-scl-wrapper[29018]: httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-ssl.conf...
Dec 07 12:34:05 ip-10-128-9-27 systemd[1]: httpd24-httpd.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Dec 07 12:34:05 ip-10-128-9-27 httpd-scl-wrapper[29020]: httpd: Syntax error on line 56 of /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /opt/rh/httpd24/root/etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/00-ssl.conf...
Dec 07 12:34:05 ip-10-128-9-27 systemd[1]: httpd24-httpd.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Dec 07 12:34:05 ip-10-128-9-27 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Dec 07 12:34:05 ip-10-128-9-27 systemd[1]: Unit httpd24-httpd.service entered failed state.
Dec 07 12:34:05 ip-10-128-9-27 systemd[1]: httpd24-httpd.service failed.
```